# CMake: set target install directory

Tags: cmake

In [Gittyup](https://github.com/Murmele/Gittyup) we are using a patched version of libgit2 which we are including as submodule into the repository. The problem is now if I wanna install the package, the patched version of libgit2 will also be tried to install to the install prefix I defined globally. On systems like Linux this makes problems with the already installed system libgit2 version because it would override files which is undesired.
The idea now is to install libgit2 into it's own prefix /lib/Gittyup/... and not installing the headers of the libgit2 target.

Is there any possibility to prevent installing those headers and setting a new prefix for the libgit2 lib?

https://github.com/Murmele/Gittyup/tree/fixCmakeInstallationPaths

Currently libgit2 is included as follow:

```
if(NOT USE_SYSTEM_LIBGIT2)
  add_subdirectory(libgit2)
  target_include_directories(
    git2 INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libgit2/include)
endif()
```

```
-- Installing: /<prefix>/lib/pkgconfig/libgit2.pc
-- Installing: /<prefix>/lib/libgit2.a
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/config.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/pack.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/oidarray.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/cherrypick.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/worktree.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/sys
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/sys/config.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/sys/cred.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/sys/alloc.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/sys/merge.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/sys/filter.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/sys/index.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/sys/credential.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/sys/transport.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/sys/diff.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/sys/refdb_backend.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/sys/mempack.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/sys/refs.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/sys/reflog.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/sys/stream.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/sys/odb_backend.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/sys/path.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/sys/repository.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/sys/commit.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/sys/openssl.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/sys/hashsig.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/remote.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/odb.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/describe.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/indexer.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/merge.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/net.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/filter.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/index.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/credential.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/transport.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/ignore.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/diff.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/notes.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/annotated_commit.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/transaction.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/stash.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/tag.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/pathspec.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/revparse.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/trace.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/graph.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/cert.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/revert.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/credential_helpers.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/refs.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/blame.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/proxy.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/blob.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/reflog.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/status.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/apply.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/global.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/deprecated.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/object.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/revwalk.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/stdint.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/odb_backend.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/rebase.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/types.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/repository.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/signature.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/errors.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/commit.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/strarray.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/oid.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/reset.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/cred_helpers.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/refspec.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/patch.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/message.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/version.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/clone.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/attr.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/refdb.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/submodule.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/checkout.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/tree.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/mailmap.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/buffer.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/common.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2/branch.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/git2.h
-- Installing: /<prefix>/./indexer
-- Set runtime path of "/<prefix>/./indexer" to "$ORIGIN"
-- Installing: /<prefix>/./relauncher
-- Set runtime path of "/<prefix>/./relauncher" to "$ORIGIN"
-- Installing: /<prefix>/./Gittyup
-- Set runtime path of "/<prefix>/./Gittyup" to "$ORIGIN"
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/applications/Gittyup.desktop
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/metainfo/Gittyup.appdata.xml
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/Gittyup/changelog.html
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/Gittyup/acknowledgments.html
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/Gittyup/privacy.html
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/Gittyup/plugin.html
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/Gittyup/emoji.json
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/Gittyup/mergetools
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/Gittyup/credential.lua
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/Gittyup/editor.lua
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/Gittyup/global.lua
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/Gittyup/lexers.lua
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/Gittyup/merge.lua
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/Gittyup/terminal.lua
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/Gittyup/update.lua
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/Gittyup/window.lua
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/Gittyup/dictionaries/Source.txt
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/Gittyup/dictionaries/de_DE_frami.aff
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/Gittyup/dictionaries/de_DE_frami.dic
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/Gittyup/dictionaries/en_US.aff
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/Gittyup/dictionaries/en_US.dic
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/Gittyup/dictionaries/es_ANY.aff
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/Gittyup/dictionaries/es_ANY.dic
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/Gittyup/dictionaries/pt_BR.aff
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/Gittyup/dictionaries/pt_BR.dic
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/Gittyup/themes/Dark.lua
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/Gittyup/themes/Default.lua
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/Gittyup/themes/System.lua
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/Gittyup/plugins/Banned.lua
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/Gittyup/plugins/Comments.lua
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/Gittyup/plugins/Line Length.lua
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/Gittyup/plugins/Whitespace.lua
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/Gittyup/plugins/banned.txt
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/Gittyup/lexers/actionscript.lua
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/Gittyup/lexers/ada.lua
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/Gittyup/lexers/zig.lua
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/locale/Gittyup/gittyup_de.qm
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/locale/Gittyup/gittyup_ru.qm
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/locale/Gittyup/gittyup_en.qm
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/locale/Gittyup/gittyup_es.qm
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/locale/Gittyup/gittyup_ja.qm
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/locale/Gittyup/gittyup_pt.qm
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/locale/Gittyup/gittyup_pt_BR.qm
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/locale/Gittyup/gittyup_zh_CN.qm
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/locale/Gittyup/qtbase_de.qm
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/locale/Gittyup/qtbase_ru.qm
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/locale/Gittyup/qtbase_en.qm
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/locale/Gittyup/qtbase_es.qm
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/locale/Gittyup/qtbase_ja.qm
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/locale/Gittyup/qtbase_pt_BR.qm
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/locale/Gittyup/qtbase_zh_CN.qm
-- Installing: /<prefix>/./libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/Gittyup.png
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/Gittyup.svg
-- Installing: /<prefix>/share/licenses/Gittyup/LICENSE
-- Installing: /<prefix>/lib/cmake/zip/zipConfig.cmake
-- Installing: /<prefix>/lib/cmake/zip/zipConfigVersion.cmake
-- Installing: /<prefix>/lib/cmake/zip/zipTargets.cmake
-- Installing: /<prefix>/lib/cmake/zip/zipTargets-none.cmake
-- Installing: /<prefix>/lib/libzip.a
-- Installing: /<prefix>/include/zip/zip.h
```

Comment: Depending on the cmake `install()` commands used in that project, you may be able to adjust the variables in the table in [the `install(TARGETS)` doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#installing-targets) (`CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR`, ect.)

Comment: But this would mean, I just install the files to another folder or?